# Unable to Modify TextView Inside Custom Adapter

Tags: java, android, custom-adapter

ok, I have a custom adapter which will display exercise, time, and whether the exercise is selected or not. When the user clicks on the clock icon inside every element in the adapter a dialogbox will show up, in which the user can modify the time for exercise. Once the time is entered the arraylist containing objects of type exercise will be updated. so the exerciseTime for that exercise object inside the list will be updated. Then the list will be refresh and the new exercise time will be displayed. but that is not the case. I can get the time to be updated. when I first create the arraylist of exercises, which I get from string.xml resource file, the default exercise time is 30min. but after the user updates, is still reflecting the time. any help apprciated.
entry_item.xml for custom adapter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/backroundColor">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/item_icon_imageview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.10"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_running_exercise"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/exercise_textview"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.40"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"
            android:text="Running"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/exercise_time_textview"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.20"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"
            android:text="30 min"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/set_time_imagview"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.20"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_timer_black_24dp"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/exercise_checkBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.05"
            android:buttonTint="@color/textColor"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

custom adapter

```
public class WorkoutAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Exercise> {

    public WorkoutAdapter(Context context, int num, ArrayList<Exercise> exerciseList) {
        super(context, 0, exerciseList);
//        allExercises = exerciseList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // Get the data item for this position
        final Exercise exercise = getItem(position);

        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.entry_item, parent, false);
        }
        // Lookup view for data population
        ImageView exerciseImageview = convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon_imageview);
        TextView exerciseNameTextview = convertView.findViewById(R.id.exercise_textview);
        TextView exerTimeTextview = convertView.findViewById(R.id.exercise_time_textview);
        final ImageView setTimeImageview = convertView.findViewById(R.id.set_time_imagview);
        final CheckBox exerciseCheckbox = convertView.findViewById(R.id.exercise_checkBox);

        exerciseNameTextview.setText(exercise.getExerciseName());
        exerciseImageview.setImageResource(exercise.getExerciseImage());


        //selected exercise checkbox
        exerciseCheckbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(exerciseCheckbox.isChecked()) {
                    exercise.setSelected(true);
                }
                else {
                    exercise.setSelected(false);
                }
            }
        });

        setTimeImageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                setTimerDialogBox(position);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), position+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    /**
     * alert dialogbox for add new item to listview
     */
    private void setTimerDialogBox(final int position) {
        // Creating alert Dialog with one Button
        final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext(), R.style.dialogBox);
        alertDialog.setTitle("Set Time");
        final EditText input = new EditText(getContext());
        alertDialog.setView(input);
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_timer_black_24dp1);

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                        long time = Long.parseLong(input.getText().toString());
                        Workout.exerciseList.get(position).setExerciseTime(time);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Time added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }).create();

        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                }).create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your var `exerTimeTextview` never set the value from your list:
You need similar to `exerciseNameTextview.setText(exercise.getExerciseName());` but with the var `exerTimeTextview`

Comment: I tried that and the wrong item gets edited. For example if I press on yoga and enter time. The time shows in running which is another item down the list